# Can I map new routes to the RouteCollection outside Global.asax?

Tags: asp.net-mvc, routes, asp.net-mvc-routing, global-asax

I'd like to occasionally map new routes to the RouteCollection during program execution long after the Global.asax RegisterRoutes() method had first executed.

How can I do this?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

It's possible, but the route collection is shared state in a multi-threaded app, so you have to get a lock. [There's an example here](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.web.routing.routecollection.getwritelock.aspx).